# Spring Webservice Template using Exception Missing Envolope tag

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using Spring webservice Template for consuming web service.

I am using SOAP version: 1.0.
and spring-ws-core version: 2.0.2.RELEASE

When I checked with SOAP UI, I got a response (FAULT, but that's fine)

This is the request/response as taken from SOAP UI: http://tinypaste.com/f77146

The configuration file looks like this : http://tinypaste.com/ce4133

Can someone please guide me ?

This is how I send the request:

```
Object response = testClientWebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8003/services/myservice?wsdl",modleRequest);
```

When trying with SpringTemplate though, this runtime error was thrown:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:260)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getImplementation(SaajSoapMessage.java:342)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.<init>(SaajSoapMessage.java:117)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:548)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:496)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:333)
    at com.test.tm.service.SpringWSClient.testProductOrder(SpringWSClient.java:60)
    at co.uti.oi.ExampleConfigurationTests.testSpringWS(ExampleConfigurationTests.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:148)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:156)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils.getSaajVersion(SaajUtils.java:155)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:257)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named "Envelope"
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.lookForEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:138)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Showing us some code would help troubleshoot the issue tremendously.

Comment: sure ! Have added the request/response as it looks in SOAP UI and also the spring configuration file. thanks !

Comment: I meant your code - assuming it's `com.bt.hqn.adslchecker.service.SpringWSClient.testProductOrder(SpringWSClient.java:60)`

Answer (score 4):

issue is resolved after removing the ?wsdl from "http://localhost:8003/services/myservice?wsdl"